# Run Python program as administrator from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run my program as an administrator from the command line.  Seems quite easy but I'm struggling.

I started with this, which works fine launched from the Python IDLE:

```
import dropbox, pymysql, shlex, shutil, subprocess
import logging
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

# Main program starts here
print("Hello World!")
```

but that gave an error as follows:

```
pi@jsmd:~ $ sudo python /home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/iot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/iot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dropbox, pymysql, shlex, shutil, subprocess
ImportError: No module named pymysql
```

After some Googling I added two lines at the start:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/")
```

This also works fine from the Python IDLE but gives a long error trace when run from the command line... and I'm not good enough at understanding how to read the trace and hence what I can do to fix it.  (Plus I don't understand why it works from the IDLE as a non-admin but not from the command line as an admin.)  Can anyone help?

```
pi@jsmd:~ $ sudo python /home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/iot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/iot_pm2/iot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sshtunnel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 25, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 50, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py", line 89, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import FortunaGenerator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 35, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import Counter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/Counter.py", line 59, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import _counter
ImportError: cannot import name _counter
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the default of python is 3 ? If not try to execute like this: sudo python3 ...

Comment: Is there any chance that the python you are running from command line is using different version of python than the python IDLE you are using?

Comment: You can check as mentioned by Telec with `which python` your python version. However, the last line tells you that there is an ImportError. There might be another package which has already defined the function _counter.

Comment: What version is your Python IDLE? Answer by pasting the stuff it prints out when you start it up; e.g. `Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` which my IDLE prints out.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you're all correct of course!  Running `sudo python...` will use Python 2 so I need `sudo python3...`.  I'd like to mark the answer from @Koffee as correct (since he/she was first to reply) but I can't - I think that's because it's a comment rather than an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the default of python is 3 ? If not try to execute like this: sudo
>   python3 ... – @Koffee

Thanks to @Koffee we have an answer and this thread can be marked as solved and closed.